# Why can't I sign into the Google Services using the Epiphany browser?

Tags: linux, debian, browser, gnome

When I go to [accounts.google.com](http://accounts.google.com) in Gnome's Epiphany, I get an error message that reads:

> Oops! Something went wrong while displaying this page. Please reload
>   or visit a different page to continue.

Why would I get this message?  Is it a page rendering issue?  This is happening for me on multiple computers running Epiphany on Gnome on Debian 8.

I am able to sign in successfully on other browsers (Iceweasel and Chromium).

Steps to reproduce:
1. On a computer running Debian 8, install Epiphany (using the package manager of your choice, or by running `apt install epiphany-browser`)
2. Launch "Web" and navigate to http://google.com and clicking the Sign In button.
3. Watch it fail.

Comment: try https://myaccount.google.com

Comment: @SeanClt I can go there successfully, but when I get to the point where I need to sign in, I have the same issue... Any other ideas?

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce it on a fresh user account on a fresh `jessie` install.

Comment: You may want to keep an eye on https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=822261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am one of the Epiphany developers. This error message means that the WebKitWebProcess that WebKit uses to render the page contents has crashed. It is a bug in WebKit. Normally, to report a WebKit crash you would get a backtrace [following these instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace) and then report the crash on WebKit Bugzilla. Unfortunately, because Debian Jessie ships with an old, unsupported, and very insecure version of WebKit, you don't want to do that; we don't want reports about ancient bugs so we'd just close the bug report. Tobia did the best-possible thing by reporting a Debian bug, but it's extremely unlikely to be fixed unless the bug is reported upstream, and it can't be reported upstream. So what to do?

Install a newer version of WebKit from [Debian Backports](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37)! This bug was fixed upstream years ago and updating WebKit should make the problem go away.

Comment: Debian sure is slow to get updates from upstream...  Nowadays, I would have known to check the Backports -- you really can learn a lot in 6 months!  Thanks for your work on developing this!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems like the answer is to just not use it.

Michael C's answer describes a backports solution.  However, the jessie-backports have the same behaviour.

According to the release notes for Jessie, at least in terms of security, **any browser other than Chromium using WebKit is unsupported because of the difficulty in backporting fixes**:

https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#browser-security

Comment: This issue has become a problem with Wheezy, but I didn't realize that it also applies to Jessie.  Thanks.